# Calling member level functions from a dynamic link library using pinvoke in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll

How would I use DLLImport pinvoke to invoke a function i wrote in a class in an unmanaged DLL?
It always throws that the entry point doesn't exist in the dll.
EX:

```
class Foo
{
  int __declspec(dllexport) Bar() {return 0;}
};
```

Bar is in the Foo class.
when I use pinvoke as:

```
[DLLImport("Test.dll")]
public static extern int Bar();
```

When using it i get an exception saying that the entry point does not exist in the DLL.
Is it possible to call functions directly from classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily...

To call a member function, the first "hidden" argument has to be a pointer to the C++ class who's member function you are calling.

And C++ functions are name mangeled, so you need to find the name mangeled name of the function you are calling.

In short: It is easier to create a C++/CLI wrapper of your C++ class to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

No

**Long answer:**

Create a C callable export (iow including the instance parameter).

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to find the mangled name.  You can use dumpbin /exports but 'im not sure that the calling convention will work through pinvoke.